# sql - sort query by other relationship count

Tags: php, mysql, sql

[image]

This is how my tables are.

So a song can have more votes.
I want to get all songs, sorted by how many votes it has.
How can I do that?

Example:
the song table would be

```
1,"Master Of Puppets"
2,"Don't Cry"
3,"Baby"
4,"Song name"
5,"I want to break free"
```

and the votes:

```
1,5
2,5
3,5
4,2
5,2
6,1
```

I want to query the song table to get the most voted songs, which should be in this order

```
5,"I want to break free"
2,"Don't cry"
1,"Master Of Puppets"
3,"Baby"
4,"Song name"
```

Is there a way to do this with only one query ?
I know that I can do a query for all songs, and then for each song query the votes table where the songId is that current song id, but can I do this with only one query?

Comment: Is there a way to do this with only one query ? Yep.  Use outer joins and a count on the votes table. (assuming you still want all songs even if it has no votes)

Comment: @xQbert you can still do it while excluding the songs with no votes if you use a `HAVING` clause.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `Count()` Aggregate to count the number of `votes` each song has got and use it in `Order by`.

`Left Outer join` is used to return rows from `song` table even though a song never got a vote

Try this

```sql
SELECT s.id, 
       s.title 
FROM   song s 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN votes v 
                    ON s.id = v.songid 
GROUP  BY s.id, 
          s.title 
ORDER  BY Count(v.songid) DESC
```

Comment: @xQbert -Yeah, initially missed to add :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT s.id, s.title FROM
(
  SELECT s.id, s.title, count(v.id) votes
  FROM 
   song s
  JOIN vote v on s.id = v.songId
   GROUP BY s.id, s.title
   ORDER BY votes desc 
);
```

can be also an option.

Comment: What If I also have a where clause? In my case it would be where playlistId = X , (a song also has a playlist id), I should use playlist = X or s.playlistId ?

Comment: "s" is only an alias, you can refer to column in table "song" also like "song.id".
This alias can help you to distinguish between columns from different tables but with the same name (and shorten the table name). So answer to your question is: yes, you can use "playlistId" when you are sure that other tables after FROM or JOIN clause don't have column "playlistId", only the "song" table. I hope it's clear. [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp) are examples..

Comment: In my case both vote and song have a playlistId. And also the table name are actually songs, and votes. and I want to select all instead of only some columns. In this case how should I change this, and also add a where clause for song.playlistId  = X ?

Comment: It that case you should use either v.playlistId or s.playlistId to avoid error "column ambiguously defined". Also, selecting all columns does the asterisk for you: "select * from ..." ...
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT s.id, s.title, s.playlistId, count(v.id) votes
  FROM 
   songs s
  JOIN votes v on s.id = v.songId
  WHERE s.playlistId = 'X'
   GROUP BY s.id, s.title
   ORDER BY votes desc 
); Something like this probably. I hope it helps.